# Bootstrap button with divider

Tags: css, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a bootstrap button with a divider inside of it.

On the left side of the divider there will be the button text aligned to the left.
On the right side of the divider there will be a plus / minus icon aligned to the center.
The divider will always be placed 33px from the right side of the button.
The divider will be colored white.

What is the best technique for creating such an effect?
(I prefer using css and fonts over images).

I cannot upload an example image cause i don't have enough reputation, but i hope you got the idea :)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: any url or any jsfiddle .. i am not getting your question exactly

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  Your resulting button looks like an existing bootstrap control called a split button (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns scroll down about a page after that link).  Adding this, when split buttons already exist, is confusing to the user.  They see the vertical divider on this (or the split button) and they are going to expect a different action depending on which side of the button they click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up defining a span inside the button (which is an  tag).
The span is on the right of the button and contains the icon. I colored its left border white and gave the right padding so it will give the icon enough space and stretch to the top of the button.

The css code:

```
.btn-blue {
    /* Button definintion*/
}

.btn-blue-right-section {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 4px 0 5px 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #86c7fe;
}

.btn-blue-icon {
    color: white;
    width: 13px;
}
```

The result image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups

```
<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn" href="#">Button text</a>
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
</div>
```

And just override the colors.

Comment: Thought about it. Problem is that I don't wont it to act as two different buttons, but as one button. I'm thinking about putting an inner span that will contain and color its left border to create the line effect (using padding to enlarge in to the edges)

Comment: I ended up using another technique, as mentioned above in my answer. But thanks for the help!

Comment: I prefer this answer: simple, precise and the more standard way to do it, when I consider accessibility, code reuse and readability. This answer is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here i am using glyphicon.

because `bootstrap button` have padding, we must remove the `padding` and move it to each `span`.

```
.btn-nopadding{
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 24px; /* optional */
}
.btn-padding{
    padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
}

/* if you want divider to left / logo at right */
.btn-divider-left{
    border-left: 1px solid #1e4d76; /* set your color here */
}

/* if you want divider to right / logo at left */
.btn-divider-right{
    border-right: 1px solid #1e4d76; /* set your color here */
}
```

here is the html

```
<!-- example for left divider / logo at right -->

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-nopadding">
    <span class="btn-padding">BUTTON NAME</span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-divider-left btn-padding"></span>
</a>

<!-- example for right divider / logo at left -->

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-nopadding">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-padding btn-divider-right"></span>
    <span class="btn-padding">BUTTON NAME</span>
</a>
```

example in fiddle : [fiddle preview](https://jsfiddle.net/c13u5t90/6/)

preview in images :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

### html

```
<button type="button" class="btn bg-blue fs-it-btn text-uppercase" aria-label="Left Align">Click me <span class="fs-it-btn-vertical-line"></span><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

### css

```
.fs-it-btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.fs-it-btn-vertical-line {
  text-align:center;
  padding: 4px 0 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
}
.bg-blue {
    background-color: #2c9deb;
}
.text-uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I have used fontawesome for the icon.